# SDWebImage weird crash com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos

Tags: sdwebimage

We are experiencing a number of crashes that is proving to be hard to debug.  Here is an extract from the crashlytics report;

```
# OS Version: 10.3.2 (14F89)
# Device: iPad Air
# RAM Free: 1.3%
# Disk Free: 23%

#8. Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
0  Nabo                           0x10039ba54 -[SDWebImageCombinedOperation cancel] (SDWebImageManager.m:327)
1  Nabo                           0x1003a03f8 -[UIView(WebCacheOperation) sd_cancelImageLoadOperationWithKey:] (UIView+WebCacheOperation.m:55)
2  Nabo                           0x10039ea8c -[UIView(WebCache) sd_internalSetImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:operationKey:setImageBlock:progress:completed:] (UIView+WebCache.m:39)
3  Nabo                           0x10039e114 -[UIImageView(WebCache) sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:progress:completed:] (UIImageView+WebCache.m:48)
4  Nabo                           0x10039e078 -[UIImageView(WebCache) sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:completed:] (UIImageView+WebCache.m:40)
5  Nabo                           0x10006caa8 __31-[NMCachedImageView loadImage:]_block_invoke (NMCachedImageView.m:34)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18fde29e0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18fde29a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18fdf2bac _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 888
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18fdf27d0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18ffeb100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18ffeacac start_wqthread + 4
```

Any clues appreciated.  I have noted there is low memory but this is a crash not an OOM issue. This is version 4.0.0 of SDWebImage using cocoapods.